# Decorator "@" on template. How does it work?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, decorator

Can anyone give me more information on using this "@" decorator in angular/ionic?

I knew the basic use to decorate a component:

```
@Component ({
   Selector: 'page-home',
   TemplateUrl: 'home.html'
})
```

I got this code below on the web, but I hate copying and pasting and not understanding fully the code. Look at this use on the "Template"! Yes not in the component, but in template:

```
<Ion-searchbar [@InOut]="varInOutState" (input)="getItems ($event)"> </ ion-searchbar>
```

Just to understand the context I'll put the snippet that @InOut appears completely inside my component.

```
    @Component ({
      Selector: 'page-home',
      TemplateUrl: 'home.html',
      Animations: [
        Trigger ('InOut', [
          State ('in', style ({
            Transform: 'translate3d (0, 0, 0)'
          })),
          State ('out', style ({
            Transform: 'translate3d (150%, 0, 0)'
          })),
          Transition ('in => out', animate ('200ms ease-in'))
          Transition ('out => in', animate ('200ms ease-out'))
        (I.e.
      ]
})
```

Could someone help me with the documentation and summarize this case in the template (I only knew the use in the component)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation is declared in the component decorator in your.component.ts and then applied to the planned HTML element using the [@] syntax.

So in your case it is `InOut` , that is defined in your component `Trigger ('InOut',...`

```
<Ion-searchbar [@InOut]="varInOutState" (input)="getItems ($event)"> </ ion-searchbar>
```

The first part matches the animations name and the given parameter is the value (‘out’ or ‘in’) from our component.

For more detail , please go through this article : [Ng2-Animation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#example-transitioning-between-states)